# CherryPy Sessions with Postgresql

Tags: python, session

I don't see any documentation on how to set up postgresql with Cherrypy.

I've tried looking up how to configure it, but I can't seem to find that. 
Does anyone have some working code they can show me on how to get sessions up with Cherrypy and postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I would probably suggest you don't use the builtin postgresql backend session as it's [clearly broken](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/748/postgresqlsession-is-incomplete-broken-and).

It just doesn't work. If you can spare the time, you'd better roll out your own backend session in this case.